# filling dynamic array in struct in C

Tags: c, struct

Hi i want to fill a struct with data so i wrote this code but when i try to run it it crush and close i don't know why :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct rectangle{
    float length ;
    float width ;
};


void main()
{
   printf("enter the size of both arrays \n");
   int x ;
   scanf("%d",&x);

struct rectangle *r ;
r = (int *) malloc(x*sizeof(int));
int j ;
 for (j = 0 ; j < x ; j++){
    printf("enter rectangle length \n");
    scanf("%d",r[j].length);
    printf("enter rectangle width \n");
    scanf("%d",r[j].width);

   }
   printf("%d \n",max(r,x));


}
```

but when i try to run it it crushes .

Comment: If `r` is a `struct rectangle *`, why are you pointing it to an array of `x` ints?

Comment: @mch: `sizeof *r`, not `sizeof r`.

Comment: I'll have some ice with that :P

Comment: Always check the result of `scanf`. If the user enters garbage, `x` is not initialised.

Comment: Take a close look at those [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) calls.

Comment: Check those return values from scanf

Comment: So few lines of code, so many faults.

Comment: By the way, what is `max` and what does it do?

Comment: I rolled back your edit because you [must not](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119) change your post to ask another question at a later point in time. When you feel you have a follow-up question, please post a fresh follow-up question. When you feel your question is not yet entirely solved, state that in an update to the post and in comments to the answerers.

Comment: Oh @Olaf ... A distinguished *poet*, and did not *know it*.... Good form.

Answer (score 2):

You are allocating an array of `int` data, yet trying to use it as if it was an array of of `rectangle` data. Both types are not the same size.

Allocate your array like this:

```
struct rectangle* r = malloc(x*sizeof(struct rectangle));
```

To clarify:

```
sizeof(int) != sizeof(struct rectangle)
```

Also `scanf` expects a pointer to each variable you are scanning in.
%d is the format specifier for integers but length and width are floats.

Use:

```
scanf("%f",&r[j].length);
scanf("%f",&r[j].width);
```

Comment: That's probably not the reasons for the crash. Look a little further down in the posted source.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg are you referring to the max?

Comment: No, the `scanf` calls.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It seems like it shouldn't even compile when scanf would expect a pointer to integer type.

Comment: That's the problem with variable-argument functions, the arguments doesn't have a specific type, so the compiler *can't* give an error. It can give warnings though.

Comment: @JustinMeiners, The pointer stay an int in both cases. The difference with your changes is that the size of the pointer is different. In a 64bit system, you're allocating 8 bytes, contrary to the original code which allocates 4 bytes.

Comment: same problem it crashes

Comment: @GangaiJohann what are you referring to? sizeof(int) and sizeof(struct rectangle) has nothing do with pointer size.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of subtle issues in your code, primarily pertaining to `scanf`, however, your use of `malloc` need not include a cast. `malloc` returns the starting address to a newly allocated block of memory. It is simply an *address* (not an `int` address or a `float` address, just an address which is type `void`). When you allocate memory, get in the habit of *freeing* the memory when no longer needed. Good habits developed now go a long way.

Putting those pieces together, you could implement your code in the following way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct rectangle {
    float length;
    float width;
};

int main (void)
{
    size_t j = 0, x = 0;
    struct rectangle *r = NULL;

    printf ("\nenter the size of both arrays: ");
    scanf ("%zu", &x);

    r = malloc (x * sizeof *r);
    if (!r) {    /* validate each and every allocation */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("\nenter rectangle values:\n\n");
    for (j = 0; j < x; j++) 
    {
        printf ("  enter rectangle length [%zu]: ", j);
        scanf ("%f", &r[j].length);
        printf ("  enter rectangle width  [%zu]: ", j);
        scanf ("%f", &r[j].width);

    }
    /* printf ("%d \n", max (r, x)); */

    printf ("\n rectangle  length  width\n");
    for (j = 0; j < x; j++)
        printf ("  r[%2zu]    %6.2f  %6.2f\n", j, r[j].length, r[j].width);

    free (r);   /* free allocated memory */

    return 0;
}
```

**note:** the return from all calls to scanf must be validated to confirm the expected number of *type conversions* took place as specified in the *format specifier* to insure that neither an *input* or *matching* failure occurred. (they are omitted above for brevity)

**Compile (with Warnings enabled)**

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -O3 -o bin/struct_dyn struct_dyn.c
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/struct_dyn

enter the size of both arrays: 4

enter rectangle values:

  enter rectangle length [0]: 1
  enter rectangle width  [0]: 12
  enter rectangle length [1]: 2
  enter rectangle width  [1]: 6
  enter rectangle length [2]: 3
  enter rectangle width  [2]: 4
  enter rectangle length [3]: 4
  enter rectangle width  [3]: 3

 rectangle  length  width
  r[ 0]      1.00   12.00
  r[ 1]      2.00    6.00
  r[ 2]      3.00    4.00
  r[ 3]      4.00    3.00
```

**Memory Error/Leak Check**

In any code your write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 responsibilites regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) always preserves a pointer to the starting address for the block of memory so, (2) it can be freed when it is no longer needed. It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you haven't written beyond/outside your allocated block of memory and to confirm that you have freed all the memory you have allocated. For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are so many subtle ways to misuse a block of memory that can cause real problems, there is no excuse not to do it. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use. Just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/struct_dyn
==18380== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==18380== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==18380== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==18380== Command: ./bin/struct_dyn
==18380==

enter the size of both arrays: 4
<snip>
 rectangle  length  width
  r[ 0]      1.00   12.00
  r[ 1]      2.00    6.00
  r[ 2]      3.00    4.00
  r[ 3]      4.00    3.00
==18380==
==18380== HEAP SUMMARY:
==18380==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18380==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 32 bytes allocated
==18380==
==18380== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==18380==
==18380== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==18380== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: My impression is, the only thing you missed is to check the return value of `scanf`.

Comment: Yep, you are correct there. It was either throw the `scanf` in a `while` loop and validate that way, or just rely on the terminal to confirm what I entered and keep the code a clean a possible for explanation purposes. So we will **note:** that the `return` from all calls to `scanf` must be validated to confirm the expected number of type conversion took place as specified in the *format specifier* insuring that neither an *input* or *matching* failure occurred. `:)`